# How can I connect two Huawei routers wirelessly to expand the WiFi Range

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, signal-strength

I have a primary Huawei EG8247H5 router supplied by my ISP connected to an Optical Fiber cable. I have another spare Huawei ONT router HG8245H and I want to connect both wirelessly in order to expand the signal range. I watched a YT video in which they said that we can "Inspect" the webpage in order to show the WDS settings by changing `stye:none;` to `style:;` (because according to him, the manufacturers do not show the feature but routers do have them, he tried it on  TP-Link and it did work in the video) which showed the option but when clicking on Enable tickbox, the field would disappear and wouldn't save. I have also tried holding WPS of both routers at the same time for 20 seconds (as suggested by my ISP, but they didn't want to help further as they wanted me to buy the secondary router from them), which didn't work. So, is there any way I can extend the range using this spare router? I have watched tons of YouTube videos but in most of them they either enable WDS or they just use it as an AP wired to the main router.

Comment: You can make anything look possible with creative editing. It’s not clear what exactly you attempted to do

Comment: A TP-Link router is not a Huawei router. Most likely both routers have nothing in common, especially not the used software so anything you have read or watched about TP-Link routers is not relevant for you. Even routers from the same manufacturer can be completely different. Additionally good Wifi repeater have multiple independent Wifi chipsets otherwise Wifi speed will be limited to less than 50%.